# how to enable continuous scrolling in iBooks 1.0 for OSX Mavericks?

Tags: books, macos, ebook

According to [press reports](http://www.engadget.com/2012/10/23/apple-ibooks-update/), Apple promised that the new iBooks app for OSX Mavericks would include an option to read books in continuous scrolling mode. Did this come to pass, and if so, how does one enable this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Continuous scrolling is available for iBooks on iOS but not the Mac. The Mac version of iBooks only allows pagination.

Comment: Do you know of an ebook reader that *does* support continuous scrolling? I can't really read without it, and I tried Adobe Digital Editions, but that doesn't seem to support it either.

Comment: @BobbyJack You can use Calibre to convert to PDF.